# $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ through $(0,h)$ and $(d,0).$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So lets say you have a function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ and you want to modify it so it hits the y-axis in h and the x-axis in d.

what i found:
$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{d}$ goes through (0,d).
$f(x)=\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{h}}$ goes through (h,0).
$f(x)=\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{h}}-\frac{1}{d}$ goes through (0, $d-\frac{1}{h}$) and ($h-\frac{1}{d}$ ,0).

$f(x)=\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{h +\frac{1}{d}}}-\frac{1}{d+\frac{1}{h}}$
gets closer and so on. But how can i find the equation that goes exactly through both points? And how do I go about solving this kind of problems?

Comment: see this https://courses.lumenlearning.com/ivytech-collegealgebra/chapter/combine-vertical-and-horizontal-shifts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a function of the form
$$f(x)=\frac1{x+c}+d$$
that passes through points $(0,a)$ and $(b,0)$ then we can choose either of two possible pairs $(c,d)$ given by
$$c=\frac{-ab\pm\sqrt{a^2b^2+4ab}}{2a}$$
$$d=-\frac1{b+c}$$
(Note that it is in fact impossible to choose such $c,d$ when $a^2b^2+4ab\lt0$ so the postive square root used always exists)

In order to find these values you just need to solve the simultaneous equations given by $f(0)=a$ and $f(b)=0$ which correspond to the required points.

Comment: i'm still in secondary school, so not sure how the quadratic formula got involved in this.  why is it $a^2 b_{1}^2$ btw, not $(a*b_{1})^2$ because you use $-ab_{1}$, so $b_{2}(from quadratic formula) = ab_{1}$. Edit: with $b_{2}$ i mean the b used in quadratic formulas, and $b_{1}$ the b in you're answer

Comment: The simultaneous equations you need to solve are $$f(0)=\frac1c+d=a$$$$f(b)=\frac1{b+c}+d=0$$solving for $d$ in the second equation and using this value in the first gives$$\frac1c-\frac1{b+c}=a$$which becomes a quadratic equation in $c$ when you multiply both sides by $c(b+c)$.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=\dfrac{d-x}{x+\frac dh}$ will be $0$ when $x=d$, and $h$ when $x=0$.

Comment: stupid me.  i see how to solve now thanks

Comment: @J.W.Tanner What if $h=-1$ or $d=0$?

Comment: @PeterForeman:  then $f(x)=-1$